# Sortable columns in Wordpress for a Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, columnsorting, wp-admin

I'm working on the admin side for a Wordpress site. I have a CPT that I've added a column into and would like to sort by that column type. Based off what I've read I'm using the correct functions, but after the filter of 'manage_edit-leadership_sortable_columns' there are no changes to the admin UI. This a CPT and the hierarchy is set to 'True.' I'd read that that may affect it but couldn't find a fix. The column also appears with a red circle and '0' next to it, that I don't know where it came from. The eventual goal is to set the display page on the site to the menu order and give the client the option to sort either by Title or Last Name. Thanks!

```
    add_filter( 'manage_leadership_posts_columns', 'smashing_filter_posts_columns' );
function smashing_filter_posts_columns( $columns ) {
    $name = array();    
  $name['last_name'] = __( 'Last Name', 'smashing', true );
  array_splice($columns, 2, 0, $name);
  return $columns;
}


function smashing_leadership_column( $column, $post_id ) {
  // Name column
  if ( 'last_name' == $column ) {
      $lastName = get_field('last_name', $post_id );
     echo $lastName;
  }
}
add_action( 'manage_leadership_posts_custom_column', 'smashing_leadership_column', 10, 2);

function smashing_leadership_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['last_name'] = 'last_name';
  return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-leadership_sortable_columns', 'smashing_leadership_sortable_columns');


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'smashing_posts_orderby' );
function smashing_posts_orderby( $query ) {
if( ! is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
    }

  if ( 'last_name' === $query->get( 'orderby') ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'last_name' );
  }
}
```

[Admin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EomlQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following code in place of the other sortable filters.

```
  add_filter( 'manage_edit-leadership_sortable_columns', 'my_sortable_leadership_columns' );
function my_sortable_leadership_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['firstName'] = 'first';
    $columns['lastName'] = 'last';
 
 
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_leadership_orderby' );
function my_leadership_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;
 
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
 
    if( 'first' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','first_name');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
    }

    if( 'last' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','last_name');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
    }
}
```